# How to compare two dataframe in pandas and show differences?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frame as mentioned below.I want to display only mismatched rows.Is there any way in pandas to do this?

**DataFrame1**

```
 emp_id emp_name    City    Salary
    111 aaa         pune    10000
    222 bbb         pune    20000
    333 ccc         mumbai  30000
    444 ddd         pune    40000
```

**DataFrame2**

```
 emp_id emp_name    City    Salary
    111 aaa         pune    60000
    222 bbb         pune    20000
    333 ccc         mumbai  30000
    444 eee         pune    40000
```

**The Output dataframe I want is :-**

```
emp_id  emp_name    City    Salary
111     aaa         pune    60000
444     eee         pune    40000
```

Comment: Join them using first three columns as a key and filter records where the last one is different. Have you tried that?

Comment: Why is `444 ddd         pune    40000` not included in the expected output? And `111 aaa         pune    10000`? In general, which columns define the 'mismatch'?

Comment: @DYZ I just want to show records from data frame 2 which are not matching with DataFrame 1.Basically I want to do ow by row comparison of dataframe 2 with dataframe 1

Comment: I think the question is clear. I can think of one solution, however it is not optimal.

Comment: What is your index? `emp_id`? In other words, how do you tell which rows to match?

Comment: Yes correct emp_id is index in my dataframe

Comment: Is it possible for a row to be missing in one of the dataframes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
df2[~df2.isin(df1).all(1)]
```

Outputs:

```
       emp_name  City  Salary
emp_id                       
111         aaa  pune   60000
444         eee  pune   40000
```

df2.isin(df1) looks like this:

```
        emp_name  City  Salary
emp_id                        
111         True  True   False
222         True  True    True
333         True  True    True
444        False  True    True
```

Comment: Nice and compact answer,1+

Comment: @PedroLobito Thanks!
 but I'm not 100% it works. But it certainly looks like it.

Comment: This won't work if there is a missing row in either of the dataframes. It will not be reported. Not sure if this situation is possible.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [concat](http://concat) and [drop_duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([["111", "aaa", "pune", "10000"],["222", "bbb", "pune", "20000"],["333", "ccc", "mumbai", "30000"],["444", "ddd", "pune", "40000"], ], columns=['emp_id', 'emp_name', 'City', 'Salary'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([["111", "aaa", "pune", "60000"],["222", "bbb", "pune", "20000"],["333", "ccc", "mumbai", "30000"],["444", "eee", "pune", "40000"], ], columns=['emp_id', 'emp_name', 'City', 'Salary'])

print pd.concat([df2,df1]).drop_duplicates(keep=False).drop_duplicates(['emp_id'])
```

---

```
emp_id emp_name  City Salary
111     aaa  pune  60000
444     eee  pune  40000
```

Comment: Nice and easy to understand +1.

Answer (score 2):

Merge the two dataframes on the employee ID:

```
m = df1.merge(df2, how='outer', on=['emp_id'])
```

Find the mismatched rows:

```
mismatched = (m.emp_name_x != m.emp_name_y) | \
             (m.City_x != m.City_y) |\
             (m.Salary_x != m.Salary_y)
```

Extract the mismatched rows, choose the columns from the second dataframe:

```
m[mismatched][['emp_id', 'emp_name_y', 'City_y', 'Salary_y']]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your objective is to check for all the rows to be same, you can use the following code

```
dataframe2.where(dataframe2.isin(dataframe1).all(axis=1)).dropna()
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to do an outer join. In order to acchieve that you could do the following:

```
result = pd.merge(dataframe1, dataframe2, how = 'outer', right_on = 'emp_name', left_on = 'emp_name')
```

So, in the previous line of code you specify which will be the column to determine the elements that will go to the result dataframe.

Comment: On the contrary, an outer join is needed to find the differences.

Comment: Oh sorry, i missread. I thought he wants the matches!. Editing!